# Make link color same as text color without knowing text color?

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

Is there some CSS that I can use to set the link color to be the same value as normal text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply set

```
a { color: inherit; }
```

edit: you may need to add

```
a { color: inherit !important; }
```

but best practices suggest you avoid using the *!important* over-ride.

Comment: Just remember *Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions don’t support the value inherit for any properties other than `direction` and `visibility`.* [Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue).

Comment: If Google isn't supporting it, I encourage other developers to push it too. http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9217279/Google_to_dump_support_for_Microsoft_s_IE7

Comment: I'd encourage everyone who can to do it. Unfortunately, the developers themselves don't always have the final say.

Comment: Those sticking clients/bosses. Why would you want the business of someone living in the stone age.

Comment: For more modern browsers you can also use `color: currentColor;`. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentColor-def

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition:

```
a{ 
  color: inherit; 
}

a:visited{
  color:inherit;
}

a:hover{
  color:inherit;
}
```